# UIScrollView scrolls to (0, 0) automatically on pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` containing one `UICollectionView` and one `UITableView` side by side with `autolayout` disabled. Origin of collectionView is (0, 0) and tableView is (320, 0). Now when a row is selected in the tableView, another view controller is pushed on the scrollView automatically scrolls to (0, 0) without animation.

Log

`2014-08-13 12:08:05.466 Flat.to[23057:613] ScrollView.contentOffset: {320, 0} 
 2014-08-13 12:08:05.466 Flat.to[23057:613] ScrollView.contentSize: {640, 500}
 2014-08-13 12:08:06.690 Flat.to[23057:613] Did select row
 2014-08-13 12:08:06.695 Flat.to[23057:613] View will disappear called
 2014-08-13 12:08:06.698 Flat.to[23057:613] ScrollView.contentOffset: {0, 0}
 2014-08-13 12:08:06.699 Flat.to[23057:613] ScrollView.contentSize: {640, 500}
 2014-08-13 12:08:07.235 Flat.to[23057:613] View did disappear called`

Because of this the pushViewController animations looks a little glitchy.

Although I can save the contentOffset in `viewWillDisappear` but is there a way to completely prevent this from happening?

Are there any function calls between `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` that I can override?

Comment: Hello Hernesh, did you find any solution since ? I have exactly the same problem here. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **viewWillAppear** method of your viewcontroller containing the scrollview will be called after viewDidDisapear of the viewcontroller which is about to popOut. There you can set the content offset of the scrollVIew.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I want it to not auto scroll in the first place instead of setting the contentOffset everytime.

Comment: Can you make it a bit clear ? where are you setting the contentOffset of your scrollView right now ?

Comment: The problem is when i select a row in the tableView, the scrollView automatically scrolls to (0, 0) because of which the collectionView shows instead of tableView during the pushViewController animation.

Comment: It seems to look like you are setting your contentOffset in the wrong place. Please update your question with code!

Comment: From your Log statements what I think is you are already setting the contentOffset of scrollView in ViewWillDissapear, instead of trying to save the state in that method try to save in ViewDidDissapear.